# Python beautiful soup arguments

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this code that fetches some text from a page using BeautifulSoup

```
soup= BeautifulSoup(html)
body = soup.find('div' , {'id':'body'})
print body
```

I would like to make this as a reusable function that takes in some htmltext and the tags to match it like the following

```
def parse(html, atrs):
 soup= BeautifulSoup(html)
 body = soup.find(atrs)
 return body
```

But if i make a call like this

```
    parse(htmlpage, ('div' , {'id':'body'}"))  or like

parse(htmlpage, ['div' , {'id':'body'}"])
```

I get only the div element, the body attribute seems to get ignored.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def parse(html, *atrs):
 soup= BeautifulSoup(html)
 body = soup.find(*atrs)
 return body
```

And then:

```
parse(htmlpage, 'div', {'id':'body'})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked. I didn't know that one could unpack lists using *, thought only dicts worked like that using *\*.

Comment: @EliBendersky Great! But any idea how we could unpack a single dictionary key (such as "class" in `del tag["class"]`)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792761/calling-and-using-an-attribute-stored-in-variable-using-beautifulsoup-4

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to add an asterisk here:

```
body = soup.find(*atrs)
```

Without the asterisk you are passing a single parameter which is a tuple:

```
body = soup.find(('div' , {'id':'body'}))
```

With the asterisk the tuple is expanded out and the statement becomes equivalent to what you want:

```
body = soup.find('div' , {'id':'body'})
```

See [this article](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) for more information on using the `*args` notation, and the related `**kwargs`.

Comment: ++, this is a nice alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i'm reading it right now.
btw I had to add two asterisks on both the parameter list and in the soup.find place.