# Calling and using an attribute stored in variable (using Beautifulsoup 4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to call a Beautiful Soup attributes (eg. class_, href, id) from a variable to use it in functions such as this one:

**script**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data='<p class="story">xxx </p> <p id="2">yyy</p> <p class="story"> zzz</p>'

def removeAttrib(data, **kwarg):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
    for x in soup.findAll(tag, kwargs):
        del x[???] # should be an equivalent of: del x["class"]

kwargs= {"class":"story"}
removeAttrib(data,"p",**kwargs )
print(soup)
```

**expected result:**

```
<p>xxx </p> <p id="2">yyy</p> <p> zzz</p>
```

---

MYGz solved the first issue using `tag, argdict` using a a dictionary as argument for the function. I then found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2571245/1486850) the `**kwargs` (to pass the dictionary key and value).

But I did not find the way for the `del x["class"]`. **How to pass the "class" key?** I tried using `ckey=kwargs.keys()` and then `del x[ckey]` but it did not work.

ps1: any idea why removeAttrib(data, "p", {"class": "story"}) doesn't work?
Ps2: This is another topic than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187082/how-can-you-set-class-attributes-from-variable-arguments-kwargs-in-python) (it's not a duplicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all credit to MYGz and [commandlineluser](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/5s9le2/how_to_pass_a_dictionary_key_to_beautifulsoup_del/)

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data='<p class="story">xxx </p> <p id="2">yyy</p> <p class="story"> zzz</p>'


def removeAttrib(data, tag, kwargs):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
    for x in soup.findAll(tag, kwargs):
        for key in kwargs:
            # print(key) #>>class           
            x.attrs.pop(key, None) # attrs: to access the actual dict 
            #del x[key] would work also but will throw a KeyError if no key

    print(soup)           
    return soup

data=removeAttrib(data,"p",{"class":"story"})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a dictionary instead:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data='<p class="story">xxx </p> <p id="2">yyy</p> <p class="story"> zzz</p>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

def removeAttrib(soup, tag, argdict):

    for x in soup.findAll(tag, argdict):
        x.decompose()

removeAttrib(soup, "p", {"class": "story"})
```

Comment: It's the not the answer I was looking for: it doesn't tell me how to call an attribute in other cases ― though I don't find any other example. But I thank you very much for this elegant solution. I found in the doc the"You can access a tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary" and the other way  to work with that, like using attrs (or class_ which is actually a shortcut)

Comment: I finally found the exemple I was looking for. `for x in soup.findAll(tag, argdict ):        del x[*key]` Please look at my question edit.

Comment: @Guillaume You didn't put the full question. I updated the answer. That is how you delete the unwanted tags.

Comment: thanks again! But decompose won't work because it destroys the tag and its contents. That's why I used the `del x["class"]`. But how to use it without using the word `class` ? That's the challenge. (I updated my question to focus on that point)